# Catch 'cannot open database' exception for a database and switch database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My question is, is it possible to catch cannot open database error?
when i give a wrong database name in my connection string I get this error on the browser
`Cannot open database "XYZ" requested by the login`

I have two connection string in `web.config` and if one database is not accessible, I would like to switch to the other database. I have tried

```
SqlConnection conn = null;
try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PrimaryDatabase"].ConnectionString);
    }
    catch 
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BackupDatabase"].ConnectionString);
    }
```

But server throws an error before hitting this part. Where should i be catching this error?

Or Am i doing it wrong and should be doing something completely different?

Comment: When are you calling the `Open` method of the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily recommend nesting try catch blocks, but since conn.Open() throws exceptions, you will want to enclose the second attempt to connect to a database in a try catch block.

```
SqlConnection conn = null;
try
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PrimaryDatabase"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    // do stuff
    conn.Close();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    try 
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BackupDatabase"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        // do stuff
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        // log or handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a breakpoint on `conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PrimaryDatabase"].ConnectionString);` line, but I get error before the breakpoint is hit and my `conn.open()` is below this (obviously). Since everybody thinks it should hit it, I must be doing something wrong. will check and follow up

Answer (score 4):

The code you have here doesn't actually open the connection. To do that you would need to use `conn.Open()`, which isn't here... which means it's outside of the `try` block, and therefore never going to get caught.

Make sure that your `conn.Open()` statement is actually inside of the `try` block and you should be ok.

Comment: I have a breakpoint on `conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PrimaryDatabase"].Connecti‌​onString);` line, but I get error before the breakpoint is hit and my conn.open() is below this (obviously). Since everybody thinks it should hit it, I must be doing something wrong. will check and follow up